# Python code to count frequent word pairs in nltk

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am confused how to find frequent word pairs in a file.I obtained the bigrams first but how to proceed from here? i tried stripping the punctuations using regexp before applying nltk.bigrams

```
raw=open("proj.txt","r").read()
tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
pairs=nltk.bigrams(tokens)
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(pairs)
finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to call `BigramCollocationFinder` without importing it. The correct path is `nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder`. So you can try this (be sure your text file has text!):

```
>>> import nltk
>>> raw = open('test2.txt').read()
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
# or, to exclude punctuation, use something like the following instead of the above line:
# >>> tokens = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+').tokenize(raw)
>>> pairs = nltk.bigrams(tokens)
>>> bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
>>> trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
>>> finder = nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(pairs)  # note the difference here!
>>> finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
>>> finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 10)  # from the Old English text of Beowulf
[(('m\xe6g', 'Higelaces'), ('Higelaces', ',')), (('bearn', 'Ecg\xfeeowes'), ('Ecg\xfeeowes', ':')), (("''", 'Beowulf'), ('Beowulf', 'ma\xfeelode')), (('helm', 'Scyldinga'), ('Scyldinga', ':')), (('ne', 'cu\xfeon'), ('cu\xfeon', ',')), ((',', '\xe6r'), ('\xe6r', 'he')), ((',', 'helm'), ('helm', 'Scyldinga')), ((',', 'bearn'), ('bearn', 'Ecg\xfeeowes')), (('Ne', 'w\xe6s'), ('w\xe6s', '\xfe\xe6t')), (('Beowulf', 'ma\xfeelode'), ('ma\xfeelode', ','))]
```

Comment: Thanks, that has solved one problem. Now to get word pairs, is it necessary to strip punctuations first? or after the last line of code 'finder.nbest' it returns the most frequent word pairs from the file

Comment: @user3182194 You can certainly strip the punctuation first if you don't want to include any punctuation. You can do something as simple as this: `tokens = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+').tokenize(raw)`. I'll update answer above.

Comment: I used it and that eliminated the punctuations. But my final output returns just two wordpairs(the most frequent according to my code) from the entire file. Changing the value of finder.apply_freq_filter(3) to 1/2 doesnt change the output?

Comment: @user3182194 It sounds like your corpus does not have many bigrams that occur more than three times. You could also make sure that you use `.lower()` to make the entire string lower-case before tokenizing it. Or you can lower the bigram frequency to 2 or 1, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want the list of word pairs.  If so, I think you mean to use `finder.score_ngrams` like so:

```
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
scores = finder.score_ngrams( bigram_measures.raw_freq )
print scores
```

There are other scoring metrics that can be used.  It sounds like you want just the frequency, but other scoring metrics for general Ngrams are here - http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn-/trunk/doc/api/nltk.metrics.association.NgramAssocMeasures-class.html

Comment: yes, i need a list of the most frequently used word pairs. i have obtained the scores of each bigram using the above mentioned code. How do i obtain the count of the word pairs? Is it possible to use FreqDist on bigrams to get their frequencies and then i can extract the word pairs with largest count

Comment: I think so, the second code block in the nltk docs Finders section is what you want - http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/collocations.html#finders